# How can I create Help Documentation for my MFC desktop application?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, desktop-application

I am creating an MFC desktop application with Visual Studio 2022 Community edition. I want to include with it some user Help documentation that will be installed with the application (i.e. should be installed locally on user computer and not accessed via the internet).

BUT I cannot see anywhere how to do this or find any tools for creating such help documentation.

Even for help documentation that is accessed via an internet connection I cannot immediately see any tools or utilities with Visual Studio that make this possible?
Are there any third party applications that allow an application developer to create help documentation?  Thanks to anyone who can advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [HelpNDoc](https://www.helpndoc.com/). With the free edition you can easily build your help documentation in CHM and HTML.

And, for either of these outputs it is quite easy to get the MFC project to display the topic. For example:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::DisplayHelpTopic(CString strTopic)
{
    CString strURL = _T("https://help-msa.publictalksoftware.co.uk/") + strTopic;

    if (theApp.UseDownloadedHelpDocumentation())
    {
        // CHM files use 3 letter suffix
        strTopic.Replace(_T(".html"), _T(".htm"));
        HtmlHelp(ptr_cast<DWORD_PTR>(strTopic.GetString()), HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC);
    }
    else
        ShellExecute(nullptr, nullptr, strURL, nullptr, nullptr, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
}
```

In your case I would compile as CHM as that can be installed on the target computer. But you could also build PDF, DOCX and / or other formats.

---

There are other applications that build CHM files (like HTML Help Workshop) but it is less fiddly with HelpNDoc as all help data is managed in one place.

- [Microsoft HTML Help Downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/htmlhelp/microsoft-html-help-downloads)
- [Microsoft HTML Help Workshop](https://www.helpandmanual.com/downloads_mscomp.html)

Comment: Many thanks!  I will check this out.  I looked for the Microsoft HTML Help app to download but the link appears dead - and I prefer not to get a copy of a product from a link that is not from the manufacturer.

Comment: @DavidH They we’re just the first links I could find. But Microsoft do expose Html Help Workshop. But I now use HelpNDoc.

Comment: I have now been able to create an initial test .CHM file, with the HelpNDoc free download, and been able to launch the resulting HTML Help window from a dedicated 'Help' menu option on the menubar in my MFC app.  BUT....the example code you supplied did not work.  I used the following code instead:

Comment: void CMainFrame::OnHelpLaunchhelp()
{
 CString strTopic = L"C:\\Temp\\MFCAPPHelp.chm";
 HtmlHelpA(GetSafeHwnd(), "C:\\Temp\\MFCAPPHelp.chm", HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC, 0);
}

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  Next steps are to work out... how to launch the Help window displaying a specific topic (rather than the entry/start point of the help documentation) AND how to specify the size and position of the Help window in the display when it is launched.

Comment: @DavidH My sample code actually shows you how to invoke a specific topic.

Comment: @DavidH Also note that my code is in the app class as a public method. And you pass to it the topic to display. And it is designed to display chm or online html. You extract the code you need.

Comment: @DavidH I think you should "Accept" this answer by clicking the "Tick" as it has addressed the original question and yiou can start a new one about contextual help.